# Send XMLHttpRequest to Java server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, http

I am trying to send an `XMLHttpRequest` to a Java server implemented using `com.sun.net.httpserver`.

This is how I am sending the request:

```
function request(progressBar,url){
    var bar=document.getElementById(progressBar);
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200){
                console.log(request.responseText)
                var progress=parseInt(request.responseText);
                bar.setAttribute("value",progress);
            }
            else
                console.log("Error: "+request.status+request.statusText);
        }
    }
    request.open( "GET","192.168.0.128:4096",true);
    request.send();
}
```

This is my Java Server:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server=HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(4096),0);
        server.createContext("/GET",new Handler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }

    private static class Handler implements HttpHandler{

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Connected to "+httpExchange.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
            byte[] bytes="50".getBytes();
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200,bytes.length);
            OutputStream stream=httpExchange.getResponseBody();
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error :

```
ajax.js:17 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
```

In the browser, sending the request like: `http://192.168.0.128:4096/GET` will return the correct value.

Comment: Try to use `http://192.168.0.128:4096` as the url of your server

Comment: I tried. I get 404 not found. I tried various combinations with no success

Comment: If you get 404 so the error is now in your server-side, and not in your javascript (which is good).

Comment: btw, you create a server with the context `/GET` but you don't use this url... you use `/` instead. Try to add `/GET` to the url you request.

Comment: Isn't the `open("GET" , url)` supposed to append the GET?

Comment: If I add GET the method `send()` throws `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'http://192.168.0.128:4096/GET' is not a valid HTTP`

Comment: Using `request.open("GET","http://192.168.0.128:4096/GET",true);` worked. I guess I don't fully understand the use of the `GET` in the `open` method. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: From the docs xhrReq.open(method, url, async);method GET is the HttpMethod you are referring to.The other GET after 192.168.0.128:4096/GET is the context root of your web application

Comment: How can I make my java httpserver make a distinction between GET,POST,..?